# Partitioning by timestamps close to each other (say 30min)

Tags: sql, teradata, partition, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a dataset where I want to partition it by timestamp close to each other(say less than 30min)

```
Driver | Timestamp
A      | 10/30/2019 05:02:28
A      | 10/30/2019 05:05:28
A      | 10/30/2019 05:09:28
A      | 10/30/2019 05:12:28
A      | 10/30/2019 07:54:28
A      | 10/30/2019 07:57:28
A      | 10/30/2019 08:02:28
A      | 10/30/2019 12:14:28
A      | 10/30/2019 12:17:28
A      | 10/30/2019 12:22:28
```

How can we partition it like below:

```
id     | Driver    |    Timestamp
1      |    A      | 10/30/2019 05:02:28
1      |    A      | 10/30/2019 05:05:28
1      |    A      | 10/30/2019 05:09:28
1      |    A      | 10/30/2019 05:12:28
2      |    A      | 10/30/2019 07:54:28
2      |    A      | 10/30/2019 07:57:28
2      |    A      | 10/30/2019 08:02:28
3      |    A      | 10/30/2019 12:14:28
3      |    A      | 10/30/2019 12:17:28
3      |    A      | 10/30/2019 12:22:28
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: because when it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What if you have one record every minute during 1 hour, will they belong to the same group or you want to break into a new group 30 minutes after the timestamp of the first record?

Comment: For the purpose, 30 minutes after the timestamp will be good.

Comment: @AyushKumar: 30 minutes between 2 consecutive timestamps, or 30 minutes after the first timestamp? FYI, the first on is easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you exactly want.

If you want to break into a new group when there is a 30+ minutes gap between two consecutive timestamps, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select
    sum(case 
        when timestamp < lag_timestamp + interval '30' minute
            then 0
            else 1
        end
    ) id,
    driver,
    timestamp
from (
    select
        t.*,
        lag(timestamp) over(partition by driver order by timestamp) lag_timestamp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: This won't work if I have three cases like it, right?
I want something which can work like a row_number() over (partition by..)

Comment: @AyushKumar: your question is unclear to me. However as far as concerns, this query will work for your sample data and produce the results that you expect. Please try it against your real data.

Comment: Perfect, I did the above and then cumulative of id, worked perfectly. Thank you so much @GMB

Answer (score 1):

Check if your version supports the `sessionize` table operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sessionize
 ( ON
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM tab
    )
   PARTITION BY driver
   ORDER BY ts
   USING
     TimeColumn('ts')
     Timeout(1800)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to sessionize you data per driver. Try this method. It appends the session_id to its respective driver to create driver specific session_id.

```
select 
   driver||sum(session_code) over (partition by driver order by timestamp) as session_id,
   driver,
   timestamp
from 
   (select 
      driver,
      timestamp, 
      case when timestamp > lag(timestamp) over (partition by driver order by timestamp) + interval '1800' second 
          then 1 else 0 end as session_code
    from your_table) a
```